# Knife Project - Extrude through thickness?

Tags: modeling, knife-tool

Is it possible to use the Knife Project tool to somehow cut through thickness and extrude the edges that are formed?
I'm trying to cut through these 4 faces (2 "cubes") but Knife Project only intercepts a hole into one face. I would like it to extrude the face through multiple planes.

Do I simply do this 4 times and connect the edges into faces manually?

[image]

Comment: There are some know limitations, which may be the cause of your problem: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Subdividing/Knife_Subdivide#Known_Issues

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5271/599

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your circle with cylinder object and do boolean difference with your main object.
[image]

Answer (score 10):

Actually, you only need one single circle here instead of two.

First, after using Knife Project, find **Cut Through** on the lowerleft corner of the Toolshelf bar, or toggle it on the <kbd>F6</kbd> panel.

[image]

Second, select each pair, then <kbd>W</kbd> ->  Bridge Edge Loops, to build faces between them (solidify the holes).

Answer (score 0):

Since the mesh you are cutting is flat , you can cut on one side

[image]

Move the circle to the other side and make a knife project

[image]

then you can start filling in the hole by making quads/Faces by using F and selectng 4 vertices .
[image]

Comment: The last step can be made much faster by using [Ctrl]+[E] > *bridge edge loops*.

Comment: I didnt know that , thats also helpful for me ^_^